# MultiBinding a TextBox Not Updating Source Property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, multibinding

I have a list box that contains a list of strings in the form of "02x06".. always two digit number, lowercase x, two digit number with no spaces.  This is bound to two text boxes, one holds the row (in this case, 02) and the other holds the column (06).

This works perfectly fine.

Now I need to bind the row text box to a Row property in code and the col text box to a Col property in code.  I am trying to do this via MultiBinding:

XAML:

```
<Windows.Resources>
     <local:DiePrintConverter x:Key="DiePrintConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox
    Name="lbxUninspectedPrints"
    ItemsSource="{Binding UninspectedPrintList}"
    Margin="5"
    Background="MidnightBlue"/>
<TextBox
    Name="txtCol"
    Style="{StaticResource txtStyle}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DiePrintConverter}">
            <Binding 
                Path="SelectedValue"
                ConverterParameter="1"
                ElementName="lbxUninspectedPrints"
                Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding
                Path="Col"
                Mode="OneWayToSource"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
<TextBox
    Name="txtRow"
    Style="{StaticResource txtStyle}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DiePrintConverter}">
            <Binding 
                Path="SelectedValue"
                ConverterParameter="0"
                ElementName="lbxUninspectedPrints"
                Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding 
                Path="Row"
                Mode="OneWayToSource"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
lbxUninspectedPrints.DataContext = wtw;
txtRow.DataContext = wtw.DiePrintNav;
txtCol.DataContext = wtw.DiePrintNav;
```

DiePrintConverter class:

```
public class DiePrintConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    bool row = true;
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value[0] == null)
        {
            return "00";
        }

        var values = value[0].ToString().Split(new string[] { "x" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (values[i].ToString().Count() == 1)
            {
                values[i] = "0" + values[i];
            }
        }
        if (row)
        {
            row = false;
            return values[0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            row = true;
            return values[1].ToString();
        }
        return "00";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

DiePrintNavigation Class:

```
public class DiePrintNavigation
{
#region Fields

    private string row;
    private string col;
    private DiePrint diePrint;
    private DelegateCommand moveUpCommand;
    private DelegateCommand moveDownCommand;
    private DelegateCommand moveLeftCommand;
    private DelegateCommand moveRightCommand;
    private DelegateCommand loadMapCommand;
    private WaferTrackerWindowViewModel wtw;

#endregion

#region Constructor

    public DiePrintNavigation() { }
    public DiePrintNavigation(WaferTrackerWindowViewModel wtw)
    {
        this.wtw = wtw;
    }

#endregion

#region Properties

    public string Row
    {
        set
        {
            row = value;
        }
    }
    public string Col
    {
        set
        {
            col = value;
        }
    }
    public DiePrint DiePrint
    {
        get
        {
            return diePrint;
        }
        set
        {
            diePrint = value;
        }
    }
    public ICommand MoveUpCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (moveUpCommand == null)
            {
                moveUpCommand = new DelegateCommand(MoveUp);
            }
            return moveUpCommand;
        }
    }
    public ICommand MoveDownCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (moveDownCommand == null)
            {
                moveDownCommand = new DelegateCommand(MoveDown);
            }
            return moveDownCommand;
        }
    }
    public ICommand MoveLeftCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (moveLeftCommand == null)
            {
                moveLeftCommand = new DelegateCommand(MoveLeft);
            }
            return moveLeftCommand;
        }
    }
    public ICommand MoveRightCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (moveRightCommand == null)
            {
                moveRightCommand = new DelegateCommand(MoveRight);
            }
            return moveRightCommand;
        }
    }
    public ICommand LoadMapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (loadMapCommand == null)
            {
                loadMapCommand = new DelegateCommand(LoadMap);
            }
            return loadMapCommand;
        }
    }

#endregion

#region Methods

    private void Move()
    {
        DiePrintQueries diePrintQueries = new DiePrintQueries(
            DataLibrary.SingulationOne,
            DataLibrary.MasksInfo);
        diePrint.Name = diePrint.Row.ToString() + "x" + diePrint.Col.ToString();
        try
        {
            diePrint.Mask = diePrintQueries.GetMask(diePrint.Name);
            diePrint.LasersPerDie = diePrintQueries.GetLasersPerDie(diePrint.Mask);
            diePrint.DieTable = diePrintQueries.GetListOfDie(diePrint.Name);
            wtw.WaferMap.DiePrint = diePrint;
            wtw.WaferMap.DrawMap();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Die Print " + diePrint.Name + " does not exist on this wafer.\n" +
                "Please move to a die print that exists.",
                "Non-Existent Die Print", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
    public void MoveUp()
    {
        // TODO: Catch all these Move Errors!!!
        try
        {
            diePrint.GetRowAndColumn(diePrint.Name);
            diePrint.Row = diePrint.Row - 1;
            Move();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
        }
    }
    public void MoveDown()
    {
        diePrint.GetRowAndColumn(diePrint.Name);
        diePrint.Row = diePrint.Row + 1;
        Move();
    }
    public void MoveRight()
    {
        diePrint.GetRowAndColumn(diePrint.Name);
        diePrint.Col = diePrint.Col + 1;
        Move();
    }
    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        diePrint.GetRowAndColumn(diePrint.Name);
        diePrint.Col = diePrint.Col - 1;
        Move();
    }
    public void LoadMap()
    {
        if (diePrint == null)
        {
            DiePrintQueries diePrintQueries = new DiePrintQueries(
                DataLibrary.SingulationOne,
                DataLibrary.MasksInfo);
            if (this.row.StartsWith("0"))
            {
                row = row.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            if (this.col.StartsWith("0"))
            {
                col = col.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            diePrint = new DiePrint(this.row + "x" + this.col);
            diePrint.Mask = diePrintQueries.GetMask(diePrint.Name);
            diePrint.DieTable = diePrintQueries.GetListOfDie(diePrint.Name);

            // TODO: dupCode(1)
            // Then map the die print
            wtw.WaferMap = new DiePrintMapViewModel(diePrint);
            wtw.WaferMap.NotifyCanvas += wtw.Update;
            wtw.WaferMap.NotifyBluetape += wtw.Update;
            wtw.WaferMap.NotifyDieprint += wtw.Update;
            wtw.WaferMap.DrawMap();
            wtw.FailureCodeManager.DiePrintMap = (DiePrintMapViewModel) wtw.WaferMap;
        }
        diePrint.Row = Convert.ToInt32(this.row);
        diePrint.Col = Convert.ToInt32(this.col);
        Move();
    }

#endregion
}
```

wtw is the view model for the window that contains all of these components.  DiePrintNav is a class that contains Row and Col write only properties that need to be updated when the txtRow and txtCol values change.  The wtw view model object contains a DiePrintNav property and is the data context of the text boxes.  The uninspected prints list box's data context is also the wtw object and is bound to the UninspectedPrintList property of wtw.

The list box is filled properly.  I can then click on anything in the list box and it is mirrored into the txtRow and txtCol boxes just fine as well, so the IMultiValueConverter class is working correctly too.

The problem is, whenever anything changes in the txtRow and txtCol boxes, their respective properties are not updated.

What is going on??

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your class `DiePrintNav` must to implemente `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Does it? That could be the reason. Check it please.

**EDIT**

---

I understand now, you want to update your model properties from the view. The problems seems to be that you need the define the ConvertBack method of your MultiValueConverter, in this way the view will be able to update all the properties when it changed. Another thing here is that the binding should be `Mode=TwoWay`, because, even if you doesn't want to update the view from the model, the first time that you load the model, you may want that the view show the old model values, in this case the two-way binding is needed. Hope this update helps...

**EDIT**

---

Please check the [MSDN IMultivalueConverter Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) article, here explains the way the `IMultivalueConverter` interface works, hope helps :)

Comment: It doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged because it does not need to.  I am trying to bind the txtRow and the txtCol values to the Row and Col properties in the DiePrintNav class.  INotifyPropertyChanged will only allow the changes in DiePrintNav to mirror into the text boxes.  I actually want to mirror what is in the text boxes to the properties in DiePrintNav.  These Row and Col properties are write-only, since there is no need to retrieve this data anywhere outside the class.  I just updated the original post with the DiePrintNav code as well.

Comment: I cant see why I need to implement the ConvertBack method.  I put a break point in there and no matter what I do, I cannot get this method to fire.  If the row and col text boxes are bound to the list box's selected value property and the row and col properties of the DiePrintNav class are bound to the row and col text boxes, I don't see how ConvertBack will ever be needed.

Comment: @RaulOtaño he would get a `NotImplementedException` if this method would called ...

Comment: For this method get called the each binding must be mode = twoway, also you may set the update source trigger = property changed. The convert back method is the one who convert (split) the value that you have in the only one text box, in the multiples values that you want set in the sources. Please check the msdn reference in the answer update.

Comment: Another thing, `NotImplementedException` can be raised, and maybe you can't see it, because the XAML hide the exception from the user, a way to see it, is taking a look to the Output console, running the app in debug mode